# How to exit bash history search mode?

Tags: bash, command-line, command-history

In Ubuntu 12.04 I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> to enter a reverse history search. If the command I want is not found (after repeated <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>), how do I immediately exit back to the (empty) command prompt with no historical command entered or executed on the command line?

Comment: I can not believe that I googled this and that it has been asked and answered already :D

Answer (score 34, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>
this will abort the search

Comment: Reference: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Miscellaneous-Commands.html

Comment: Both answers here are wrong. This will exit the search, but **not** "back to the (empty) command prompt with no historical command entered". Whatever search result came up will be entered on the command line, and worse, you will now be at that point in the history stack as well. At least as my bash is configured I cannot replicate any situation where **no** result is returned - even entering nonsense will leave me in the history stack at whatever matched the first couple letters.

Answer (score 18):

You can use:

- The Emacs style keyboard quit command, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd>. Default key bindings in `bash` are purposefully Emacs-like.
- The Vi style return to normal mode key bindings, <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>[</kbd> (they're the same thing) .
- Send a SIGKILL signal, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>.

The first two have the least visible effect.

Comment: {Grin}  You can prevent the display of "^C" if you add `stty -ctlecho` to your startup files (.bashrc,.profile,.zshrc, etc)  Now ALL three methods have least visible effect.

Comment: for some reason Esc and Ctrl-C do not work on the Ubuntu systems I have tried (including my current 12.04).

Comment: @lornix: I *like* to have visual feedback of Ctrl-C. Just imagine the psychological impact of pressing Ctrl-C before submitting a command like `rm -rf /` (extreme example), going away, then coming back to the terminal. There's practical joke potential in this, of course.